# SQL Query in Excel PowerPivot

Tags: sql, excel, powerpivot

I have an issue when I try to validate my SQL query and says 'A column name can not be blank'

I have previously been able to get a shortened version without joining the two table together.

```
SELECT [dbo].[StockTransactions].[TransactionNumber], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[ActivityDate], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SiteCode], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[CommodityCode], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[CommodityVarietyCode], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[BinGradeCode], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleMoistureQty], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[Partition], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleProteinQty], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleTestWeight], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleRetentionQty], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleScreeningsQty], 
SUM([dbo].[StockTransactions].[Unshrunktonnes]), 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleSkinningsQty],
[dbo].[Vw_Oms_Sampleresults].[TestCode],
[dbo].[Vw_Oms_Sampleresults].[Result]



FROM [dbo].[StockTransactions] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Vw_Oms_Sampleresults] 
ON ([dbo].[StockTransactions].[Stocktransactionsomsid]=[dbo].            
[Vw_Oms_Sampleresults].[Stocktransactionsomsid]) 

WHERE (([dbo].[StockTransactions].[Activitydate]>'1/10/2016' 
AND [dbo].[StockTransactions].[Transactiontype]='GROWER RECEIVAL                     
' 
AND [dbo].[StockTransactions].[Businessunitcode]='ausbulk' 
AND (NOT [dbo].[StockTransactions].[Ownername]='shrink') 
AND [dbo].[StockTransactions].[Commoditycode]='WH' 
AND [dbo].[StockTransactions].[Seasonlongcode]='2016/2017' 
AND [dbo].[Vw_Oms_Sampleresults].[Testcode] IN ('FF', 'FR', 'FS', 'SNL') 
AND [dbo].[StockTransactions].[Sitecode] IN ('ARN', 'BUC', 'COW', 'CUM', 'CUN', 'DAR', 'EDI', 'ELL', 'KIE', 'KIM', 'KPI', 'KYA', 'LIN', 'LOC', 'MAN', 'MDA', 'MIN', 'NEI', 'NUN', 'PEN', 'PNT', 'POO', 'RUD', 'STB', 'THE', 'TOO', 'TUM', 'UNG', 'WAD', 'WAR', 'WHA', 'WIT', 'WRL', 'WUD', 'YAN', 'YEE'))) 

GROUP BY [dbo].[StockTransactions].[TransactionNumber], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[ActivityDate], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SiteCode], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[CommodityCode], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[CommodityVarietyCode], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[BinGradeCode],
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleRetentionQty], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleMoistureQty], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleSkinningsQty],
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[Partition], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleProteinQty], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleTestWeight], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[SampleScreeningsQty], 
[dbo].[Vw_Oms_Sampleresults].[TestCode], 
[dbo].[Vw_Oms_Sampleresults].[Result], 
[dbo].[StockTransactions].[PartitionStorageType]
```

Any help why this could be throwing back the error?

Comment: Try giving your SUM column an alias like `SUM([dbo].[StockTransactions].[Unshrunktonnes]) AS TonnesSum`

Comment: Yes! Looks like there is something about the SUM it didn't like. I took it off and just had them all listed and it worked.